# Proper MSSQL query with PHP on IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I am new to the IIS and MS SQL world.

I have followed tutorials on how to form my connection to MS SQL and while I do not get any errors, I get a blank screen.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
$db_server = "Server";
$db_name = "Database";
$connInfo = array( "Database"=>"$db_name");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($db_server,$connInfo) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

?>

I am using a LAMP server so this is uncharted territory for me.

Comment: Start by turning on error reporting - add this to the the top of your file - `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: After adding the above to the top of my file, I still get just a blank page.   My php.ini is set to show all errors.